# How to restore journal on ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I've a lot of messages stuck in journal after un crash.

I'm trying to restore them. So I use recover command with this following command (before I've stopped the broker):

```
./artemis data recover --journal ../data/journal --target ../data/recovered --large-messages ../data/large-messages
```

I've any error messages, but the messages seems not be in queue. I'm new to ActiveMQ Artemis so I'm not sure.

- Do you know to check if my message go back to queue? I'm currently check with:

  ```
  ./artemis queue stat --maxRows 500
  ```
- Topics are missing. Recover should be restore them before?

Comment: What do you mean you have "a lot of messages stuck in journal after un crash"? Please elaborate and clarify. The `recover` command is meant to recover messages that have been acked or rolled back (i.e. "removed" from the broker's view but not completely deleted from the journal). It's not clear to me why you're using it in your situation.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: I'm using v2.10. An amqp service connect to activemq-artemis crash. After the crash,  I have purge and delete accidentally all topics. I've seen data are still available in the folder /journal (data-XXX.amq files). So I would like to know if there a way to restore  message in the queue?

Comment: What do you mean you "purge and delete accidentally all topics"? What _exactly_ did you do to "purge and delete"?

Comment: I purge and delete queue with cli. Command was ./artemis queue purge nameOfTheQueue     ./artemis queue delete nameOfTheQueue